# SharePoint domains and Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, dns, cqwp

I have created a new sharepoint site on our moss server at http://sharepoint:12345 and added a CQWP to it without issue.

I have a domain name pointing at the same server. So I pointed to http://myinternaldomain.whatever:12345 and for some reason the CQWP then breaks, saying unable to display this web part?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Crank open the ULS logs in your 12hive/logs. There should be an entry for the error that will provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up an Alternate Access Mapping for the second domain?

[AAM on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have but not pointing to this site, would that be an issue?

Comment: That's the first thing I would check. SharePoint often doesn't behave if the URL used to access it doesn't have an AAM. As Nat suggests, check the logs for a detailed error message.